# jquery fancybox focus issue

Tags: jquery, fancybox, focus

I have a form that open in a jQuery Fancybox Window.
The fancybox window opens automatically when the page loads. When it loads, I want it to set focus on the username field in the form in the Fancybox window.
I have found that this must be done when fancybox is envoked, thus I have tried the given code that does not work :Code snippet:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$("#hidden_link").trigger('click');
document.getElementById('username').focus(); 
});
```

The form name is "login_form" and the field ID is "username".

Comment: what version of fancybox?

Answer (score 1):

i don't quite sure what version you use.

i assume that you use version 1
so try to add this options when call fancybox

- onStart           Will be called right before attempting to load the content
- onCancel  Will be called after loading is canceled
- onComplete    Will be called once the content is displayed
- onCleanup Will be called just before closing
- onClosed  Will be called once FancyBox is closed

this come from fancybox api documents http://fancybox.net/api

and add function that you want to use.

in this case

```
$('#somediv').fancybox({
    oncomplete: function() {
        document.getElementById('username').focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: this is my actual code :   jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "loadCustomerDetails.php",
      success: function(msg){
       $('#customerDetails').html(msg);
       $("#hidLinkCustomerDetails").fancybox().trigger('click'); 
       $('#txtCustomer').focus(); 
      }
      });

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to call focus() before the fancybox appears. Instead of putting that call in ready(), put it in onComplete().

```
onComplete: function() { 
          $('#username').focus(); 
}
```

Comment: its just triggering the fancybox....jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "loadCustomerDetails.php",
      success: function(msg){
       $('#customerDetails').html(msg);
       $("#hidLinkCustomerDetails").fancybox().trigger('click'); 
       $('#txtCustomer').focus(); 
      }
      }); ..this is the actual code

Answer (score 0):

I have to use setTimeout to solve this problem.

> onComplete: function() { 
>       setTimeout(function() {
>           $('.sms_code')["1"].focus();
>           }, 1000);  }